# Unable to start spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am unable to start my application using @SpringBootApplication.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppInitializer.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AppInitializer().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(AppInitializer.class)).run(args);
            System.out.println("count="+ctx.getBeanDefinitionCount());
        }
}
```

pom.xml uses:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

When i run the app, i get below error:

> 2015-03-09 09:14:10.372  INFO 10636 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with
>   port(s): 9000 (http) 2015-03-09 09:14:10.636  INFO 10636 --- [
>   main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
>   Tomcat 2015-03-09 09:14:10.638  INFO 10636 --- [           main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine:
>   Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 2015-03-09 09:14:10.940  INFO 10636 ---
>   [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
>   Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2015-03-09
>   09:14:10.941  INFO 10636 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 3588 ms 2015-03-09 09:14:11.936 ERROR
>   10636 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   :
>   A child container failed during start
>
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 common frames omitted
>   **Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addFilter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Filter;)Ljavax/servlet/FilterRegistration$Dynamic;**
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean.onStartup(FilterRegistrationBean.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 common frames omitted

Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.34:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java6:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile (version managed from 1.7.5)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile - omitted for dupli
cate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile - om
itted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.
0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compi
le - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:co
mpile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile - omitted for dupli
cate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile - om
itted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compil
e
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Fi
nal:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version man
aged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omit
ted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:runtime - version managed from 1.7.7;
 omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile (version managed fr
om 4.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version man
aged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version
managed from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version m
anaged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - omitted for
 duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version manage
d from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile (version manage
d from 4.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version manag
ed from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version man
aged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - omitte
d for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version man
aged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version man
aged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
 from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.4:compile (version managed from 1.8.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; sc
ope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- qcom.cas.backend.myapp:service:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (qcom.cas.backend.myapp:persistence:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted f
or duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.3.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version m
anaged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compi
le
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; o
mitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; o
mitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; o
mitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.8:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; o
mitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
 from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:runtime
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
- omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.4:compile (version ma
naged from 2.4.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile - omitted for duplicat
e)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version manage
d from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
 from 4.0.7.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)

[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted
for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplic
ate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for d
uplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)

[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted
for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplic
ate)
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted
for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
- omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)

[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicat
e)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile - omitted for dupli
cate)
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for
 duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.14:comp
ile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.14:comp
ile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicat
e)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)

[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:config-types:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:core:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for dup
licate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for dupli
cate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:core:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)

[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jvnet:tiger-types:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplic
ate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-runlevel:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplica
te)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for dup
licate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:class-model:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:asm-all-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version m
anaged from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version manage
d from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
 from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.14:compile - omitted for dupl
icate)
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile - version mana
ged from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile - version
managed from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.3.2:compile - omitt
ed for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile - version mana
ged from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile - version
managed from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.3.2:co
mpile
[INFO] |     |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.4:compile - version m
anaged from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile - versi
on managed from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.4:compile - version
managed from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile - omitt
ed for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
- omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.4:compile - version manage
d from 2.3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile - omitted for duplic
ate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed fr
om 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed fro
m 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version manage
d from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
 from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version mana
ged from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile - version managed
from 3.2.3.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:provided (sc
ope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.57:provided (version managed
from 8.0.15)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.57:provided (version managed fr
om 8.0.15)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.57:provided (version
managed from 8.0.15)
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:7.0.57:provided (version man
aged from 8.0.15)
[INFO] |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.57:provided - version man
aged from 8.0.15; omitted for duplicate)
```

Comment: Is this your whole pom.xml? Please post all dependencies. It looks like there is a version conflict in the servlet api jar.

Comment: Added the dependency tree for your reference. There are jersey-container-servlet-core & jersey-container-servlet jars.

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem: The dependency jersey-container-servlet-core is only suitable for servlet containers with less than Servlet 3.0 specification. Since you use Tomcat 7, which implements Servlet 3.0, you have to use jersey-container-servlet. See the Jersey documentation here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#servlet-app-general

If you run the application as standalone app (i.e. not deploy it into Tomcat), you have to make sure, that the dependency spring-boot-starter-tomcat is in scope "compile". Currently the dependency has the scope "provided", which means, the dependency is not on the classpath when running the application.

If you want to run your application both in Tomcat and as standalone app, you have to use Maven profiles and build two WARs, one with spring-boot-starter-tomcat as provided, and one with spring-boot-starter-tomcat as compile.

Comment: I added exclusion in pom for jersey-container-servlet-core. It throws different error now:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String;
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)

Comment: The main reason is the same, there is still a conflicting API version. Do you use an IDE? If so, can you search for the class ServletContext, and look how many occurrences of this class you have, and in which JARs? There should only be one occurrence coming from a Tomcat jar.

Comment: I am using GGTS IDE and it doesn't show any occurrences of ServletContext :-( .

Comment: Ok, then i have no more ideas :(

Comment: I tried different IDE to check for occurrences. ServletContext is coming from tomcat-embed-core-7.0.57.jar only.

Comment: How do you start/deploy your application? Do you start it with "java -jar yourwar.war" or do you deploy it to another appserver?

Comment: The method getContextPath is only available since Servlet 2.5. So in some way in your runtime there might be a servlet api jar with a version less than 2.5.

Comment: If i deploy the war in tomcat, it works. When i run the app via main() within IDE, it throws this error.

Comment: I've updated the pom configuration (refer above pom configuration that i edited) as per your suggestion and still same error:

Comment: On a plain old J2EE project migrating to Spring, I had a similar thing - a dependancy on servlet 2.5. Thank you.