# Spring boot built Failed, Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

My Spring boot applicatoin is running successfully on my windows machine, but when I tried to run on ubuntu, it got built failed.

My java is 1.8.

```
sudo apt-get install maven
mvn clean install -DskipTests
java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Result:

```
2016-12-12 13:27:32.656 ERROR 13606 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at com.dac.khmer.CkmComputerApplication.main(CkmComputerApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        ... 6 common frames omitted

2016-12-12 13:27:32.657  WARN 13606 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2016-12-12 13:27:32.699 ERROR 13606 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at com.dac.khmer.CkmComputerApplication.main(CkmComputerApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [nervenet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:116) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.niptict</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>KhmerLib</name>
<description>Library for all</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: did you look inside the `logs/catalina.out`?

Comment: No, I don't know how to check. help me please.

Comment: Which dependencies do you have on your pom.xml file?  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934952/unable-to-start-spring-boot-application

Comment: I have added pom.xml, may u check it please. The provided link I couldn't find solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you don't have dependencies to different versions of Tomcat? Can you show your hole pom.xml file?

Comment: Don't know if your problem is resolved. I had similar issues and found out that one of the dependencies is built with an older version of servlet-api. Springboot doesn't want you to include the servlet-api, but if the dependency is built with an older version, then you will see this error.